# Resharper assigns same key sequence for different actions?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-9.0

I'm using the latest Resharper (9) with visual studio 2012.

The VS shortcut key for comment/uncomment text is  : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>u</kbd>.

But when I click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> for quick documentation (as I;m used to and as we all know) :

[image]

it comments the line ! :

[image]

I've searched in the keyboards shortcuts and found that Resharper also assign this sequence to  comment ! :

[image]

**Question**

What is going on here? is there anyway to "reset" the shortcut settings ( not via `devenv.exe/resetsettings` but only for resharper?)   , and besides why this is happening ? how can it assign same keys for different actions ?

Comment: This happened to me too, and I had to go find an old [twitter exchange](https://twitter.com/hmemcpy/statuses/446370005836648449) to try and remember what I did... I think it was one of the extensions, remapping the incorrect key. Do you happen to have the Bing code search thing installed? I think I got rid of that. Also, re-apply your shortcuts from the ReSharper options.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik Looks like it is the same behaviour . Thank you

Comment: I somehow suspect this also has something to do with launching Visual Studio when the Hebrew layout is selected. If you happen to launch VS when Hebrew is selected, the default shortcut for 'Search in Solution explorer', which is `Ctrl-;` is turned into `Ctrl-ף`, which is the same key in Hebrew. For some reason or other, the `Q` key is also the `/` in Hebrew, so this might explain *how* `Ctrl-Q` is replaced with `Ctrl-/`, but not why...

Comment: @IgalTabachnik Yes But this is inconsistent with my computer at home which also have R#9. there , it works.  also some colors has suddenly changed. pretty weird.Thanks for your replies.